# How to catch "Unable to sendViaPost to url"?

Tags: java, web-services, exception, apache-axis, axis

I am running two axis2 services which communicate with each other. On every service startup I get this error:

```
2014-02-24 13:02:31,258 [INFO ]           HTTPSender  - Unable to sendViaPost to url[http://127.0.0.1:8081/axis2/services/MYSERVICE1.MYSERVICE1HttpSoap12Endpoint/]
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ReflectionSocketFactory.createSocket(ReflectionSocketFactory.java:140)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:125)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:621)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:193)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:404)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:231)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient$NonBlockingInvocationWorker.run(OutInAxisOperation.java:446)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Since this error is not important, I would like to catch it and to print some better error message instead of the whole stack trace. Where do I catch this error?

Comment: ¿How are you starting the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the stack trace, I don't think you can catch it. Catching it would require that you own code somewhere in the Thread where the exception is being thrown.

Looking at the lowest stack in the trace shows this:

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

To me this says that the exception is occurring in a thread most likely started by Axis.  Because of this you can't catch it and show an error message.

If this is expected behavior, the best you can do is to configure your logging framework not to show INFOs from Axis.  Be aware that this may mean you'll also miss more useful error messages as well.

All in all, I would focus on how to solve the "Unable to sendViaPost" from happening rather than suppressing the logging statement.

**To answer your comment question:** As you can see from the stack trace, the exception is not caught by any client code but is bubbled up to Thread itself.  This is the stopping point for an  Exception and where it stops.  If you were going to catch it you'd have to have code in its call stack (which you don't, since when the thread is created by Axis a new call stack is created for the new thread Axis starts).

Read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html). The only difference in your case is that since the exception is not thrown on the main thread the program doesn't exit, but the thread where the exception occurs is terminated.

*To sum it up:  You have no code in the call stack and therefore cannot catch the exception.  The only other option is to turn of INFO statements for Axis.*

Comment: Yes, to me it also seems that this is a message thwrown by the Axis, and caught by who? Apache?

Comment: See my response at the end of my answer.

Comment: OK, thanks Jason. Still not convinced 100%, but no more time to loose. Thanks.

Comment: I hear you.  If you've got time I invite you to try out the other methods if you want to see for yourself. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the question properly you're attempting to catch something that is not the exception that is being thrown.

This:

> HTTPSender  - Unable to sendViaPost to url[http://127.0.0.1:8081/axis2/services/MYSERVICE1.MYSERVICE1HttpSoap12Endpoint/]

is what is being attempted.  When it failed it's throwing a ConnectException.

Which you can simply catch with

```
try{
    //Code that Makes the Connection
}
catch (ConnectException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();//Or What ever your message may be
}
```

Without seeing some code it's impossible to give a definitive answer.  But this likely will solve the problem.

One Caveat, if you do catch a ConnectException to suppress it, you could suppress when there actually is a problem that would also throw a ConnectException.

If this is happening when you are starting up the server you might want to check why this is happening before trying to suppress it.

If it's refusing the connection that you are attempting you might want to ensure where it is connecting to has an available socket to connect to.

Answer (score -1):

> 2014-02-24 13:02:31,258 **[INFO]**           HTTPSender  - Unable to
>   sendViaPost to
>   url[http://127.0.0.1:8081/axis2/services/MYSERVICE1.MYSERVICE1HttpSoap12Endpoint/]

Well, if you look closely, the message which you are trying to catch isn't an `ERROR` at all. It's an `INFO` log generated from `HTTPSender`. Only thing which you should catch in this entire `stacktrace` is `java.net.ConnectException` and check for message `Connection refused`.

You can make it easier for your clients though and provide a message, by wrapping the `java.net.ConnectException` with message `Connection refused` or throwing a custom exception with the original exception as the cause.

**UPDATE**

`java.net.ConnectException` is an elementary exception in network transactions. Generally standard libraries do not catch them unless there is **something specific** to be done.

In this case, if you are unable to catch hold of `java.net.ConnectException`, then you can look out to catch `AxisFault` thrown by `org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send`.

Below snippet may be useful for you.

```
try {
    ...
} catch (RemoteException ex) {
    if(ex instanceof AxisFault){
        logger.error("Axis Fault error: " + ((AxisFault)ex).getFaultString());
        throw new CustomExcpetion(" Custom Message ");
    }
}
```

Also note that `AxisFault` is a subclass of `java.rmi.RemoteException` and this will not get caught when you use `java.lang.Exception` in a `catch` statement.

Shishir

Comment: How do I do that? Have a look at Jason Nichols answer. Thanks.

Comment: That will not work.  You can't catch an exception unless you have code in the stack where the exception is thrown!

Comment: Catching AxisFault is possible in every way. Since it is not the subclass of Exception, you are not able to see it in the stacktrace. The last logical point OutInAxiaOperation throws out AxisFault and moves on to logging the native thread path. Dont get confused between normal Exception & RemoteException.